# Retrieve and zip up word docs from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, zip

I have an ASP.NET app that uses a SQL Server 2005 database to store word documents. One of the application requirements is that when a user clicks a button, the system retrieves some number of word documents from the db, zips them up in memory and allows the user to save the zip file to disk.

Is there a zip library that provides the ability to zip up files in memory? The few that I've seen read from the file system.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since Word2007, the documents are compressed by design. Zipping them will only make them bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to do this.  You can back it with a memorystream and write the bytes out to the response once they're compressed.

Answer (score 2):

With [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) you can create in memory zip streams.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) to do something very similar. Light weight, easy to use, no problems encountered.